# MySQL Client with settings across devices

Tags: mysql

Is there any MySQL client with which I can save settings (*connection info, authentication, port etc*) and it'll be available to usable by my other devices? For SSH I'm using Termius and I need software for MySQL version like that.

Platforms (*all would be better*)

- Linux (ubuntu)
- macOS
- Windows

I'm using these platforms simultaneously...

I hope I explained my need properly

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's your price range, which software have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: Price is not a big deal. At Windows, I'm using MariaDB, macOS DBeaver. They are good but my biggest requirement synchronised session list (server information, credentials, etc). I don't want to enter server's information to all 2-3 platforms every time